# Looping Over Json Structure To get Multiple Outputs, I'm getting one, Why?

Tags: python, json, firebase

Hello I'm a new face to json and I want to ask something about it, anyway here's my code:

```
for key in result1date.keys():
    key = sorted(result1date.keys())
    currentdate = key

    print currentdate

    result1 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/' + currentdate + '/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/', None)
    result2 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/' + currentdate + '/Inspection/Scan-out/Inspector/', None)
    print result1

    print currentdate

    for key in result1.keys():
         inspector = key
         timeout = result2[inspector]["Time"]

    # for key in result1date.keys():
    #    Date = key

    result1datetime = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/'+ currentdate +'/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/'+ inspector +'/', None)

    for key in result1datetime.keys():
        key = sorted(result1datetime.keys())[-2]
        time = key
        print time

     print time

     ch1 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Entrance louver clean and dust-free"]
     # ch2 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Room plate number – clean and well-polished"]
     ch3 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Appearance door surface- in good condition"]   
     # ch4 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Let the door close by itself to test the door closure – in working order"]
     ch5 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Eye viewer and fire escape plan in order"]
     ch6 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Privacy Sign or Make Up Room Sign"]
     # ch7 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Key card holder – in working order"]
     ch8 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Switches at the entrance working correctly"]

    #CLOSET
    #ch9 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Let the door close by itself to test the door closure – in working order"] 
     RESERVED FOR DOOR IN WORKING CONDITION
     ch10 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Lights in working order"] 

    # items below are sufficient
     ch11 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["6 Hangers?"]
     ch12 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["2 bathrobes?"]
     ch13 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["2 pairs of slippers?"]
     ch14 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["1 set of iron and board?"]
     ch15 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Elsafe open or working?"]
     ch16 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["1 set of laundry list and bag?"]
     ch17 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["1 extra pillow with pillow cover?"] 
     #ch18 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Luggage bench fabric top is clean"]#DINING DRESS CODE
     #ch19 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Luggage bench fabric top is clean"] #FLASHLIGHT

     #LUGGAGE AND LUNCH BREAK
      ch20 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Luggage  bench fabric top is clean"]
      # ch21 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Drawers – clean and dust-free"]

      #MINIBAR
      #ch22 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Luggage bench fabric top is clean"]#Arrangement of the items is neat & clean.
      #ch23 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Luggage bench fabric top is clean"]#Ensure the items below are sufficient
      ch24 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["2 coke, 2  sprite, 1 C2 lemon, 1 C2 apple, 1 pineapple juice, 1 orange juice, 1 mineral water, 2 San Mig light, 2 pale pilsen?"]
      ch25 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["1 pringles, 1 cashew nut, 1 cup noodles (placed in the coffee tray on the writing desk)?"]
      ch26 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Fridge is cold and clean"]
```

I have three dates. 'currentdate' so i looped all over them hoping to get the same output but three of them with different dates. Here's my firebase structure:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfYSP.png)

But I'm only getting one. when I looped all keys using this part of the code

```
 for key in result1date.keys():
     key = sorted(result1date.keys())
```

the ones below should have followed it. Any help is appreciated. I want to know why is this happening and hopefully a solution or a suggestion.

I want to get an output of something like this:

```
[DATE 1 HERE with all the details within its branches]
[DATE 2 HERE with all the details within its branches]
[Date 3 HERE with all the details within its branches]
```

Comment: You should make your example much more minimal.

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
for key in result1datetime.keys():
    key = sorted(result1datetime.keys())[-2]
    time = key
    print time
```

You're iterating through your keys in the `for` loop, but then you always get the same key in the next line (`sorted(result1datetime.keys())[-2]`).

Why did you add that line in the first place?  This way, you're always getting the middle key (out of three).

Perhaps you wanted to sort the returned key instead (`key = sorted(key)[-2]`).  Your structure image does not show deep enough to know what to expect in that level.

In any case, I'd recommend you not to reuse the `key` variable inside the loop like that.  It will make things hard to understand.  And note that the problem is resetting it for a fixed element of the same iterable you were looping on in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with python or json so this might not work in your case but did my best building this, hope it can be of some help

If the Json file has a fixed stable structure or if the values are even quite similarly formatted, I was thinking you could do this:

**Json sample as dict**:

```
firebase_json = {
"Rooms": {
    "Room1": {
        "2017-11-29": {
            "Status": ["unoccupied"],
            "Inspection": ["yes"],
            "Scan-in": ["no"],
            "Scan-out": ["yes"]
            },
        "2017-12-05": {
            "Status": ["occupied"],
            "Inspection": ["no"],
            "Scan-in": ["yes"],
            "Scan-out": ["no"]
        },
    },
    "Room2": {
        "2017-11-02": {
            "Status": ["unoccupied"],
            "Inspection": ["yes"],
            "Scan-in": ["no"],
            "Scan-out": ["yes"]
        },
        "2017-12-01": {
            "Status": ["occupied"],
            "Inspection": ["no"],
            "Scan-in": ["yes"],
            "Scan-out": ["no"]
        }
    }
}}
```

**sample selections**

```
room = input("Room?",)
for a in firebase_json:
    for b in firebase_json[a]:
        if b != room: #select by given room.
            continue
        print(b)
        for c in firebase_json[a][b]:
            print(" ", c) # if selection by date add previous != statement here
            for d in firebase_json[a][b][c]:
                for e in firebase_json[a][b][c][d]:
                    print("   ", d, ":", e)
```

There is possibly a better way of doing this but as I said.